# htaccess url rewrite with virtual language folders doubles page name as folder in URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a small PHP website with 3 pages. The page content is dynamically translated in Dutch or English (I take the language from the URL)

```
\index.php
\page-one.php
\page-two.php
```

I want to achieve the following URL's

```
https://www.example.com/ => https://www.example.com/en/ or nl/ depending browser language
https://www.example.com/en/ => \index.php
https://www.example.com/en/page-one/ => \page-one.php
https://www.example.com/en/page-two/ => \page-two.php
https://www.example.com/nl/ => \index.php
https://www.example.com/nl/page-one/ => \page-one.php
https://www.example.com/nl/page-two/ => \page-two.php
```

It works locally on my PC with WAMP with the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!(en|nl)/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^nl/(.*)$ /$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!(en|nl)/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
RewriteRule ^en/(.*)$ /$1 [L]
```

However, when I publish it on the shared webhosting (at OVH) the sub-folder with the page name points to the index file

```
OK https://www.example.com/ => https://www.example.com/en/ or nl/
OK https://www.example.com/en/ => \index.php
NOK https://www.example.com/en/page-one/ => \index.php
NOK https://www.example.com/en/page-two/ => \index.php
same for the /nl/
```

The pages only show as follow

```
https://www.example.com/en/page-one/page-one/ => \page-one.php
https://www.example.com/en/page-two/page-two/ => \page-two.php
```

But also these URL's works, which should not be the case

```
https://www.example.com/en/page-one/page-two/ => \page-two.php
https://www.example.com/en/page-two/page-one/ => \page-one.php
```

It seems that it runs line 10 and 14 of the htaccess twice.

How can I solve this?

Comment: "The pages only show as follow `https://www.example.com/en/page-one/page-one/ => \page-one.php`" - On the (live) shared hosting? And/or locally? How are you managing your static assets (JS, CSS, images, etc)? Are these being linked to with the appropriate language prefix? But then they are rewritten to remove this? What filesystem directories do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a conflict with `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation). This would explain how this is able to work at all locally and the difference in behaviour on the live server (where I suspect MultiViews is not enabled). (Although it does not seem to explain how `/en/page-one/page-one/` seemingly "works" on the live server? This would, however, work locally with MultiViews enabled. The same applies to `/en/page-one/page-two/` - more on that below.)

In your mod_rewrite directives you are not appending the `.php` extension at any point, so by themselves they cannot possibly work (unless you are requesting `page-one.php` - with the `.php` extension - directly). So, it looks like you are relying on MultiViews (which effectively appends the file extension).

> But also these URL's works, which should not be the case
>
> ```
> https://www.example.com/en/page-one/page-two/ => \page-two.php
> https://www.example.com/en/page-two/page-one/ => \page-one.php
> ```

It is MultiViews that allows something like this to "work". Although I would expect this to be the other way round. ie. `/en/page-one/page-two/` would serve `/page-one.php`, not `page-two.php` as you suggest?

What happens here is that your mod_rewrite rule internally rewrites a request for `/en/page-one/page-two/` to `/page-one/page-two/`. MultiViews then initiates an internal subrequest to `/page-one.php/page-two/` (`/page-two/` is simply PATH-INFO) and `/page-one.php` is served.

---

You need to ensure that MultiViews is disabled. And then manually append the `.php` extension where appropriate. However, you've not stated how you are managing your static assets (JS, CSS, images, etc.)? Should these be subject to the same redirect/rewrites? Are these language specific also?

I would assume you are linking directly to the static assets, so these should not be subject to URL-rewriting.

Try something like the following instead:

```
# Ensure that MultiViews is disabled
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Abort early if request has already been rewritten
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} .
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Abort early if request maps to a file OR directory (except root)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

# Append trailing slash to non-assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Prefix request with language code if omitted (302 - temporary)
# (Defaults to "en" if not "nl" or omitted)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language}@en (?:^|@)(nl|en)
RewriteRule !^(en|nl)/ /%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]

# Rewrite to remove language prefix and append ".php" extension if file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(?:en|nl)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

# Otherwise, rewrite to remove the language prefix (handles the DirectoryIndex)
RewriteRule ^(?:en|nl)/(.*) $1 [L]
```

The `RewriteBase` directive in your original rule block was not required (and it's not required here either).

No need to check `THE_REQUEST` since we are aborting early when the request has already been internally rewritten (by checking against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable - which is empty on the initial request and set the to HTTP status after the first successful rewrite).

If on Apache 2.4 then you can use the `END` flag, instead of `L`, on the last two rules (both rewrites) and remove the first "Abort early" rule that checks the `REDIRECT_STATUS` env var. The `END` flag stops all processing so no "loop" occurs.

Further improvements... consider redirecting the request if `index.php`, `page-one.php` or `page-two.php` (ie. anything with a `.php` extension) are requested directly.

Comment: Great idea with the default language pointing to english! I love this second rewritecond solution!

Comment: @PatrickJanser Thanks, although I've actually removed that 2nd `RewriteCond` (to default the language) since it can all be done in a single _condition_ (but it's really just personal preference).

Comment: @ChrisAelbrecht I've also updated my answer to address a couple of bugs... **#1** I had neglected to account for the (enforced) trailing slash when appending the `.php` extension. **#2** Also neglected to remove the language prefix for requests to the root (in order to serve `index.php`) - I've added an additional rule to cover that. Also added a bit more explanation.

Comment: @MrWhite thank you for your detailed response. It almost works. Only issue I have is that www.example.com (with or without a trailing slash) doesn't redirect to www.example.com/en/ (or nl). I did manage myself by combining my previous solution with yours, which also solved all other issues. I'm pasting my answer in a separately.

Comment: @ChrisAelbrecht Ah yes, sorry. You just need to change the first `RewriteRule` _pattern_ from `^` to `.` so as to exclude requests for the root directory itself (otherwise the later rule that prefixes the lang code is bypassed). ie. Change the line `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` to `RewriteRule . - [L]`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Nice idea to have a single RewriteCond to detect the language and default to a `en`. I'm just thinking about persons having mulitple languages set (typically in Switzerland we speak French, German, Italian and often know English too). So matching with `^` might be a problem as I typically have `accept-language: fr-CH,fr;q=0.9,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-CH;q=0.6,de;q=0.5`. This means that people that speak `nl` but don't have it as prefered language could be redirected to `en` even if they don't speak english.

Comment: @MrWhite, I tested again and now effectively it goes from www.example.com to www.example.com/nl/, but it keeps on redirecting. The browser throws the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS. The other pages www.example.com/nl/page-one do still work

Comment: @ChrisAelbrecht Ah dang, yes, having changed that `^` to `.` it now doesn't block looping (due to internal rewrites) when rewriting back to the root. I've split the first ("Abort early") rule into two to account for this. Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @MrWhite his reponse the following .htaccess does what is expected

```
Options -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# Append trailing slash to non-assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^nl
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!(en|nl)/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /nl/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+(?!(en|nl)/).*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R=302]

# Abort early if request has already been rewritten OR maps to a file OR directory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite to remove language prefix and append ".php" extension if file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(?:en|nl)/([^/]+)/$ $1.php [L]

# Otherwise, rewrite to remove the language prefix (handles the DirectoryIndex)
RewriteRule ^(?:en|nl)/(.*) $1 [L]
```

Comment: The two-line language-code redirect in my answer would have still been OK. It was the "abort early" rule that was in error since it also caught requests for the root directory (so the later rule that prefixes the language-code was skipped). I've updated my answer to address this. However, these rules are now in the wrong order. The "abort early" rule should be first in order to prevent static assets from being unnecessarily redirected. (Although it perhaps wouldn't matter if you are referencing _all_ static assets with a language code prefix?)

Comment: I reference all static assets with a leading slash which automatically redirects to /en or /nl...

Comment: "which automatically redirects to /en or /nl..." - The static assets themselves should not be redirected?